# Generate a Pre-signed URL Using the AWS SDK for Java

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk, pre-signed-url

I was following the example from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html to create pre-signed s3 urls (v4) and I get **Access Denied** error when I try to access the signed the url

```
<Error>
   <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
   <Message>Access Denied</Message>
   <RequestId>0FB02ECDDF5EAC7B</RequestId>
   <HostId>vA+mmsv9PCunNe5uPkPrmpqqN3vFctQ13c9dIRlKWTYsT0zNA1V9g+4YS+lCItrBlyQtdHpyspg=</HostId>
</Error>
```

The following is the code snippet

```
public class GeneratePresignedURL {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String clientRegion = "us-east-1";
        String bucketName = "com-example-bucket";
        String objectKey = "path/to/file.img"; // No leading `/`
        // https://com-example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/file.img

        try { 
            AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();

            // Assuming that us-east-1 defaults to v4, couldn't find a way to set it explicitly
            AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withRegion(clientRegion)
                    .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider)
                    .build();

            // Set the presigned URL to expire after 10 minutes.
            java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
            long expTimeMillis = expiration.getTime();
            expTimeMillis += 1000 * 60 * 10;
            expiration.setTime(expTimeMillis);

            // Generate the presigned URL.
            System.out.println("Generating pre-signed URL.");
            GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = 
                    new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objectKey)
                    .withMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                    .withExpiration(expiration);
            URL url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);

            System.out.println("Pre-Signed URL: " + url.toString());
            /*
                sample signature:
                https://com-example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/file.img?X-Amz-Security-Token=FQoDYXdzEDcaDLjUOdj2hDTZvWUQaiK3AxulqM%2BOPlp%2Bnq71P0LyuI0vj8tT%2F9i24Wd3jY8dUbudWbhUH9IAsPnl7asujO90GlaFP4dXujDDLwIakMjCJSfOFM4IoGJz8XtcjXkqJCNaenbrTA%2F3PfSl%2Fe9wQwJlY8gOu8%2Byioq2ElHULMKv52nEZj8s3v4dD0pGHQTYc4hGV7ty9CYwXNgz6w3TREhxuFdAewNgTRnY1uFNy7on6NDF5IE15vlJ2PxqrX53ZMLKP%2FdU8i5BcpZ3ySVhNpBpU3GJAPMOh%2B2ztCAk1zPjW4G0N5n9BlnjTMGs3vGBb9IW%2F8dzAoxaG9U9%2B%2FCp8euJN562dYYSZ9wmQgsfOVqc5OksdnHVkPJW400ObOcKmc9mqIRyqA%2B3Mv4z0%2Fx6iLYRJ3UaloFSGbmR6VlIxMl%2F67aHrmCnBE23a1%2BNMWgzLx%2FogqZy3CD%2F%2Fs6Jt1qkxUrRwC0RPK93LHD74qm8rjqZcEKFrBOrZsYtcl3zKgRIEHCbatQ7dwT634sdF0MwaD0vwTsbsStZDW903k5C%2FDuz4rEmkPv6c5CmFvxp4xOkUtMbDk4B8Z641CoeAMMOKICH%2FlW7%2F1as3nQo07Ow2QU%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20180621T214222Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=3000&X-Amz-Credential=<access_key>%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=<signature>
            */
        }
        catch(AmazonServiceException e) {
            // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process 
            // it, so it returned an error response.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(SdkClientException e) {
            // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the client
            // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The signature format seems to be correct and I am not sure if I am missing some other s3 client config.
Since I don't get a signature mismatch error or invalid url error, I assume that the Access Key used to sign the url is correct.

Answer (score 9):

Here are steps to generate aws-s3 pre-signed url to access the content stored in s3 through java can create with simple step

1. First add maven dependency in your pom

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
>   <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
>   <version>1.11.870</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

2. Get S3 credential **`accessKey, secretKey, region`** of s3 storage it must needed
3. Write java class
4. First get s3Client connection using below code snippet providing your own credential

> ```
> BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
> final AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new 
> AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds)).withRegion(region).build();
> ```

5. You must have your **`bucketName`** if you don't have create bucket and store your content
6. Use below code snippet to generate pre-signed url

> ```
> // Set the expiry time
> java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
> long expTimeMillis = expiration.getTime();
> expTimeMillis += 1000 * 60 * 60;
> expiration.setTime(expTimeMillis);
> ```

7. Pass your objectKey is noting but your existed s3 base filename

> ```
> GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest =
> new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objecKey)
> .withMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
> .withExpiration(expiration);
> URL url = s3client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
> System.out.println("Pre-Signed URL: " + url.toString());
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the region mismatch. You have set clientRegion to be **us-east-1** but if you are accessing it from any other region it will give **access denied** error. You can only access the object from **us-east-1** region or just change it to your region. It's **ap-south-1** for Indian clients.

Comment: Shouldn't this have enforced **us-east-1** as the region
 AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withRegion("us-east-1")

Comment: I tried the same code you presented, my default region is also us-east-1 and the code too enforces the presigned url to be available in us-east-1 . When I tried to open the url in my browser , I got access denied error as , being an Indian user my browser is accessing ap-south-1 . Hence when I changed region to ap-south-1 , I am able to access the presigned url successfully

Comment: I am accessing it from US and have set the region to **us-east-1** and having fixed bucket access permission issues, it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that the role didn't have permissions to access the s3 bucket **path/to/file**

Answer (score 0):

Try to add **.withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)** as mentioned in below snap.

```
// Assuming that us-east-1 defaults to v4, couldn't find a way to set it explicitly
       AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                        .withRegion(clientRegion)
                        .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
                        .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider)
                        .build();
```

Change/check this change CROS properties of AWS S3 bucket.

```
<CORSConfiguration>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>

   <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>

   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
 </CORSRule>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be mindful of assigning the cognito auth-role with access to S3 else the permission will be denied in case you are using the cognito-credentials user pool session to provide the required access to s3client. This was an issue which i was facing as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
          import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
          import com.amazonaws.HttpMethod;
          import com.amazonaws.SdkClientException;
          import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
          import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
          import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
          import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
          import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
           import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList;
           import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.DeleteObjectRequest;
           import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GeneratePresignedUrlRequest;
           import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectListing;
           import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3Object;
           import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectSummary;




          <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
                 <version>1.11.163</version>
         </dependency>


                  String GeneratePresignedUrlAndUploadObject() {

                    String accesskey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
                    String secretkey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
                    String bucketName = "your-bucket-Name";
                    Regions regions = Regions.US_EAST_1;
                    String objecKey = "your-file-name-you-need-url";

                    BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(accesskey, secretkey);
                    //
                    final AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds)).withRegion(regions).build();

                    // Set the expiry time
                    java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
                    long expTimeMillis = expiration.getTime();
                    expTimeMillis += 1000 * 60 * 60;
                    expiration.setTime(expTimeMillis);

                    GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objecKey)
                            .withMethod(HttpMethod.GET).withExpiration(expiration);
                    //
                    URL url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
                    System.out.println("Pre-Signed URL: " + url.toString());

                    return url.toString();
                }
```